# wxWidgets in visual studio showing : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'wxmsw29ud_core.lib'

Tags: c++, linker, wxwidgets

i able to setup wxWidgets 2.9.4 correctly on windows 7 x64. sample projects are working fine. but when a try to make a new project is show error

`fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'wxmsw29ud_core.lib'`

i setup project according to information provide at 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11515/Introduction-to-wxWidgets
http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B_Guide#Changing_setup_settings

i also try to put Depenedencies form running sample projects. but again it show the same error 
and if i put my code in one of running project then i works fine.
i also try to run vs with admin.

Comment: yes i add location of \lib and \include as provided at both of links

Comment: You need to add \lib\vc_lib.  See my answer.  Do not add \include to linker, that goes in C/C++

Comment: actually i add full path for lib and include directories. sorry for writing in short. i find cause of that. this is because version 2.9.4 use `${WXWIN}\include\msvc` directory but i use that given in guide. thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the  location of the library to the list in the linker section of the project settings

Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### For wxWidgets 3.0 above

If you're using wxWidgets version later than 2.9, most likely **the solution is to update the library name** `wxmsw28ud_core.lib` into `wxmswXYud_core.lib`, where `X` is the major number and `Y` is the minor number of the wxWidgets version you're using.

For example, as of this writing I'm using wxWidgets 3.1. So I simply specify `wxmsw31ud_core.lib` instead of the faulty `wxmsw29ud_core.lib` as instructed by outdated guides for Visual Studio such as [WxWiki](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B_Guide#Project_properties). The same is done for `wxbase28ud.lib`.

Comment: Note: wiki is not the official guide. The official one is [docs/msw/install.md](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/master/docs/msw/install.md) and, in particular, it describes how you can avoid having to update the library versions by using `wxwidgets.props` instead.